# Bounty not credited to accepted answer

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, bounties

I've provided an answer on a question with a bounty, however once my answer was accepted I was not credited the bounty. The question in question is:

[Ruby/Rails: accessing a variable inside a .each on my instance variable array causing Ruby interpreter to crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7314987/ruby-rails-accessing-a-variable-inside-a-each-on-my-instance-variable-array-ca/7349243#comment9050544_7349243)

Comment: When did the bounty expire?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you can see in the question's [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/7314987/revisions):

> Bounty Ended with no winning answer by Community♦ (Sept. 16th)

So the bounty was not awarded by the person who started it. Accepting an answer doesn't award the bounty.

If I understand the question's [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/7314987/timeline) correctly, you answered on Sep. 8th and got an upvote on Sep. 12th. You got a second upvote on Sep 19th, i.e. *after* the bounty period was over.

According to the [bounty FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work), for an automatic bounty award, you would have needed two upvotes before the 16th to get (half) the bounty amount.

---

<sub>From the bounties I have been awarded, here's what a manually awarded bounty looks like in the revisions: [manual award](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/5079168/revisions)

And here is an automatic (half) bounty award: [automatic award](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/5134297/revisions)</sub>

Comment: Perhaps accepting an answer *should* award the bounty.  I mean, the action of accepting an answer by definition says "this is the answer i think is best" -- can you think of any non-sneaky case where that answer *shouldn't* get the bounty?

Comment: That used to be the case, but it is not anymore. The FAQ mentions it: [As of June 2010, the bounty system is decoupled from accepting an answer.](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/improvements-to-bounty-system/) (blog link). The [bounty privilege](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/set-bounties) says the same: "* You can accept an answer without awarding a bounty to it. *  You can award a bounty on an answer without accepting it.". This is by design.

Comment: As for why this could be useful, the "Reward existing answer" bounty reason in particular (or the spirit of it anyway) applies. If you accepted a great answer that got lots of votes, but have other answers that are also great (and possible required a lot of work form their authors) but didn't get as much attention, awarding your bounty to other answers makes sense.

Comment: Good investigation, @Mat - you are correct.

Comment: Thanks guys for clarifying, seems slightly unintuitive. perhaps a nice popup to the poster of the question after accepting it to remind them that they should award the bounty would be helpful?

Answer (score 4):

It's worth noting that the rules of the bounty system have changed since this question was originally asked. Under the [current rules](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty), the answer *would* be awarded the bounty if it was accepted.

> If the bounty was started by the question owner, and the question owner accepts an answer during the bounty period, and the bounty expires without an explicit award – we assume the bounty owner liked the answer they accepted and award it the full bounty amount at the time of bounty expiration.